# How to add same function for two classs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is a jQuery code that already works how I want. `.foto` class do the function. But I should to add `.fotoleft` class to do the same function. How can I do the same function for two different classes?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".foto").click(function() {

        $src = $(this).attr("src");
        if (!$("#light-box").length > 0) {
            $("body").append("<div id='light-box'> <span class='close'></span><img src=''></div>");
            $("#light-box").slideDown();
            $("#light-box img").attr("src", $src);
        } else {
            $("#light-box").slideDown();
            $("#light-box img").attr("src", $src);
        }
    });

    $("body").on("click", "#light-box", function() {
        $("#light-box").slideUp();
    });
});
```

Comment: Where are you adding the classes? Also, did you know that you can chain methods? e.g. `.addClass('foto').addClass('fotoleft')` --- You can also put to classes in one `.addClass('foto fotoleft')`

Comment: `$(".foto, .fotoleft")`?

Comment: It's **well-worth** your time to read through [the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com) from beginning to end. It only takes about an hour, two tops, and it repays you that time almost immediately.

Comment: I tried much ways. I think I used comma in wrong place so it didn't work before. I learnt truth from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `.fotoleft` to perform the same function as `.foto`, I find the most efficient way of doing this would be to use `.foto` in your html twice, rather than in your JS twice.

I prefer this method as it makes it easier to apply a function to multiple or additional elements without needing to add more classes to the JS.

i.e.

```
<a class='foto'>Do Something</a>

<a class='foto fotoleft'>Do Something too></a>
```

You could choose to amend your css to make `.foto` more compatible in this way so you don't overwrite any styling.

Comment: thank you. All ways work but I like your way and use it.

Comment: No problem.  It makes it easier to also make a unique class like `.btn` if you want to have a mouseover cursor.  I also have this as a separate class, with `.btn { cursor: pointer; }`, then add it to whichever elements I need.  This would, in this example, give you `<a class='foto fotoleft btn'>Do Something too, with a mouseover cursor</a>`.
Everyone will do things differently, but it's just my choice to have concise JS and CSS in this way, as it's easier to then amend many buttons with 1 class.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to use [Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```
$(".foto, .fotoleft ") .click(function(){
    //Your existsing code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You use [groups](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#grouping) (via a comma); these are CSS selectors, after all:

```
$(".foto, .fotoleft")...
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
$(".foto, .fotoleft") .click(function(){
```